# get the value from edittext and set that in the custom listview

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

As a beginner succeeded to create a custom list.
here is the java class of the custom list:
and i did implement OnClickListener

```
public class Area_Acre extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
String[] stringarray = new String[7];
private EditText editAcre ;
private ListView list ;
private Button buttonConvertAcre;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.area_acre);

    Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById (R.id.buttonConvertAcre);
    EditText editAcre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAcre);   
    buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(this);

    setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            R.id.textView_list,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Area)));
}
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, parent,false);
        String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Area);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView_list);
        TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_list);

        tv.setText(items[position]);

        if (items[position].equals("Acre")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.area_acre);
        }

        else if (items[position].equals("Hectar")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.area_hectar);
        }

        else if (items[position].equals("Square Inch")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.area_sinch);
        }

        else if (items[position].equals("Square KM")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.area_skm);
        }

        else if (items[position].equals("Square Meter")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.area_smeter);
        }

        else if (items[position].equals("Square Mile")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.area_smile);
        }

        else if (items[position].equals("Square Yard")){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.area_syard);
        }

        return row;
    }
```

here is my on click, which i have no idea how to do it. **I have been taking the value to textview and now i want to take the value from the edittext into the custom listview**

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.buttonConvertHectar){  
        double acre = Double.valueOf (editAcre.getText().toString());
        double hectar = acre * 0.404686;
        double squareinch = acre * 6.273e+6;
        double squarekm = acre * 0.00404686;
        double squaremeter = acre * 4046.86;
        double squaremile = acre * 0.0015625;
        double squareyard = acre * 4840;
    }
        stringarray[0] = acre + "";
        stringarray[1] = hectar+ "";
        stringarray[2] = squareinch+ "";
        stringarray[3] = squarekm+ "";
        stringarray[4] = squaremeter+ "";
        stringarray[5] = squaremile+ "";
        stringarray[6] = squareyard+ "";

}
```

and here is the xml:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonConvertAcre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:text="@string/Button" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/viewline_hight"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/insideline_marginUpDonw"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/insideline_marginLeftRight"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/insideline_marginLeftRight"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/insideline_marginUpDonw"
        android:background="@color/inside_line" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/linearlayout_marginhight"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/linearlayout_marginLeftRight"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/linearlayout_marginLeftRight"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textAcre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Acre"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="@dimen/main_text_size" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editAcre"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_marginLeft"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:hint="@string/IYN"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/red_set"
            android:textSize="@dimen/hint_text_size" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/viewline_hight"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/insideline_marginUpDonw"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/insideline_marginLeftRight"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/insideline_marginLeftRight"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/insideline_marginUpDonw"
        android:background="@color/inside_line" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the custom list view xml:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_list"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/e_incalc" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="@dimen/main_text_size" />
```

that's it ...
appreciate any help,
and thanks a lot

[this is how the app look like at the first place.. Click](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-VsNCcyrQiP4/UiNR6cIH1NI/AAAAAAAAACU/VOrXV8CFfY8/w346-h479/1.png)

this is how i want it to be... with edittext and listview and a button or it would be better if i can get the result automatically.
[this is how i want it to be with listview..Click](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-objnD9-X43A/UiNSKpDg1YI/AAAAAAAAAC4/06HLKgQSAKY/w381-h527-no/2.png)

Comment: I didn't understand your problem well. BTW good formatting for a beginner (Y).

Comment: thanks ... i want to get the value from the edittext which is editAcre and get the result to my custom listview.

Answer (score 0):

Add your "textview.Text" string to the stringArray.

and Code for the listview in android:-

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.yourLayoutName, stringarray);


            // Assign adapter to ListView
            listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

            // ListView Item Click Listener
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                     int position, long id) {

                   //Your business logic goes here

                  }

             }); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question, but here is how you could use the onClick() method

You have defined a Button `buttonConvertAcre`, so in your onClick method you can do:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == buttonConvertAcre) {        
        // now you want to receive the value of the edit text as an Double or Integer, right?
        String valueString = editAcre.getText();
        Double value = Double.valueOf(valueString);

        // now do your calculation
        value = value * 0.404686; // I would recommend to use static final variables for calculation

        // now you want to set the result to your TextView, right?
        // make sure your TextView is initialized, e.g.
        // TextView acreResultTextView = findViewById(R.id.acreResultTextView);
        // Note, if you like to change a TextView within your listAdapter, then you can
        // do the calculation in the adapter using the TextView in the adapter at its positon
        // in your case: R.id.textView_list
        acreResultTextView.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }
}
```

Note, that I've use the `editAcre` in onClick, this requires that you change your onCreate() method to initialize this variable:

```
private EditText editAcre ;
private ListView list ;
private Button buttonConvertAcre;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.area_acre);

    // now use your private variable defined in the class
    editAcre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAcre);   
    buttonConvertAcre = (Button) findViewById (R.id.buttonConvertAcre);
    buttonConvertAcre.setOnClickListener(this);

    setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            R.id.textView_list,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Area)));
}
```

This should help you getting started.

Best regards, 
Michael

[EDIT]: Here is a solution when using LinearLayout instead of the ListView and list adapters..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/convertButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="convert"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Acre:"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="enter value"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/imageAcre"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textViewAcre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Acre:"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textViewAcreValue"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1.0283"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Now doing the same for Hectar ... -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/imageHectar"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hectar:"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textViewHectarValue"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2.024"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Now doing the same for all others. Simply copy the layout and rename the image, the text and the id -->     

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Mothy ..Hello, i will try your method ... i am so slow :)

Comment: @ Michael ... hello, i want to take the result to the listview :)

Comment: i already made it with the textview .. but its much better and easier with listview ... i can save a lots of time and layouts with listview method as i understood from some tutorials.

Comment: What is your goal? Would you like to have an EditText and a single convertButton and if you click on the button you like to calculate all values (and the values are shown in the listview)?? Because then I don't get the idea why you are using a list view, instead of a LinearLayout and using fixed TextViews, e.g. textViewResultOfHectar, textViewResultOfSquareKm, etc.
Can you post a screenshot of your app, please?

Comment: EDIT: I've fixed the onCreate() method above to use the correct button `buttonConvertAcre.setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: i posted 2 images for you to see how it was and how i want it. and i can't post any images so that's why i posted those in my g+ i hope they work.

Comment: the links of the images are above in the end of my post

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. For this layout I would recommend you to use a LinearLayout instead of the ListView. ListViews are for lots of data, you have a few (and fixed) number of output labels.

Comment: I've edited my solution.. This is how you would use a LinearLayout instead. You need to complete it for SquareKm etc.. I just added Acre and Hectar.. Hope it helps. In the code you would use the calculation as I explained. Then you would simple update multiple TextViews in your onClick() method, e.g. `TextView acreTextView = findById(R.id.textViewAcreValue);
acreTextView.setText(String.valueOf(acreValueFromEditText);

Double hectarValue = acreValue * 0.404686;
TextView hectarTextView = findById(R.id.textViewHectarValue);
hectarTextView.setText(String.valueOf(hectarValue);`

Comment: Hello Michael ... why you are using this ...android:text="1.0283" ??

Comment: what i have is a converter!! that means you can input any number in that.

Comment: converting for example Acre to hectare or celsius to Fahrenheit and so on. and i just gave you an example what i already made for my app with LinearLayout. and i have Area .. temperature, speed and few other

Comment: this is my app on google play [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mini.world.econverter4kids&feature=search_result)... you can see the pictures better

Comment: and this is another app what i made with spinner. so simple interface. [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mini.worlld.econverter)..

Comment: i feel shame cause i didn't used listview :(

Comment: Ok, so you really want to use ListView instead of a LinearLayout? Why is it a shame? Like I said, a list view is for usually for lots of data, e.g. like all contacts in a phonebook. If you converting a value from an EditText to calculate a value in multiple TextViews, I think its the easiest and also a smart way to use a LinearLayout, instead of iterating through all elements of a ListView and change its values.

Comment: The value 1.0283 (and also the 2.024) was a random value.. you can leave it empty, it was just for the preview while I created the LinearLayout.

Comment: @user2513275 I was wondering if you were able to solve your problem? I found a great tutorial on Custom ListView's which I can highly recommend to you. [Here it is](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)! If my answer helped you, you should accept it :)